# Consuming RESTful response via Angular service

Tags: angularjs, json, rest

I'm following scotch.io's [tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4) on building a RESTful API while trying to get familiar with the MEAN stack.

I've followed pretty much everything so far, and got my RESTful API sending out JSON as intended. Should I try to access it via browser address bar or try it out with Postman it works.

I'm having problems with the consumption of said JSON response.

According to the tutorial, the Angular app is divided in *controllers* and *services*. The service uses `$http` to call the RESTful endpoint. My doubt is where and how should I use that service to call for the data.

Is it in the controller? Is the *service* exposed in a way that I can add its response to `$scope`?

I'm new to Angular/client-side routing, so please be gentle:) My code is below.

**(Blog) Controller:**

```
angular.module('BlogCtrl', []).controller('BlogController', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.tagline = 'Blog page!';

    // can and should I call the service here?

});
```

**Service:**

```
angular.module('BlogService', []).factory('Post', ['$http', function($http) {

    return {
        // call to get all posts
        get : function() {
            return $http.get('/api/blog');
        }     

}]);
```

**Routes:**

```
angular.module('appRoutes', []).config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider

        // blog page that will use the BlogController
        .when('/blog', {
            templateUrl: 'views/blog.html',
            controller: 'BlogController'
        })        

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

}]);
```

**Angular App:**

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'appRoutes', 'MainCtrl', 'BlogCtrl', 'BlogService']);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can make $http call in your `BlogController`.

However if you want to use your 'Post' factory, you should inject it to controller

```
angular.module('BlogCtrl', []).controller('BlogController', function($scope, Post) {...}
```

and make the request

```
Post.get().then(
  function(response){console.log(response.data)},
  function(errorResponse){/*...*/}
);
```

(I think you should also read about `$resource` (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource). Maybe it is something what you could use to replace your `Post` factory ;))

Comment: no need to create  `new` instance, factory doesn't return `this` like a service does

Comment: Thank you for replying! Unfortunately, it isn't working. Nothing shows up at console, either response or errorResponse. Any thoughts?

Comment: @akn my bad... had linting active. It's working, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You want to inject the service into controller ( or anywhere else you would use it) and then make the function call using the injected service object

```
angular.module('BlogCtrl', [])
    .controller('BlogController', function($scope, Post) {

    $scope.tagline = 'Blog page!';

    // Use service to get data
    Post.get().then(responsePromise){
     $scope.someVariable = responsePromise.data;
    }).catch(function(err){
       console.warn('Ooops error!')
    });        

});
```

Comment: Note that `BlogService` is a module name and `Post` is his factory name, so it probably won't work ;)

Comment: Thank you for replying! sadly it's not working. If I assign `responsePromise.data` to `$scope.posts`, wouldn't `ng-repeat` be able to use `x in posts`? Also, I think something could be wrong with your syntax. could you please check?